# Robot Framework browser support

Tags: selenium, robotframework

Has the robot framework support for IExplorer or only for Firefox and Chrome?
(If yes, how to configure it?)

Thanks!

Comment: Please give feedback if you need more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Robot Framework does not, in itself, support any particular browser, so I am guessing you are referring to either SeleniumLibrary or Selenium2Library which use selenium and selenium 2 respectively. The browser support of these is well documented at seleniumhq and there is much support out there. It is recommended for new projects to use Selenium2Library as this will receive ongoing support.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My problem now is that the tests I wrote for Firefox  don't work under IE. :-(

Comment: if you have any specific problems feel free to post them on here, I subscribe to email alerts for the [robotframework] tag ;)

Answer (score 0):

Download `IEdriver exe` from [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/)  and put this exe file in *Scripts* folder of your *Python* installation directory. For eg, in my case it is `C:\Python27\Scripts`.

Ride will now launch *IE* for you.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the driver compatiblity for browser.

Answer (score 0):

Open Browser    `${WEBAPPURL}    ${BROWSER}` is the keyword to open the browser.

- For *Firefox* you can use `firefox/ff` instead of `${BROWSER}`
- For  *Google Chrome* you can use `googlechrome/gc/chrome` instead of `${BROWSER}`
- For *Internet Explorer* you can use `internetexplorer/ie` instead of
  `${BROWSER}`

For *Firefox* you don't need any driver but *IE* and *Chrome* you need to install the drivers

You can find the installers in and info [here for Chrome](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver) and [here for IE](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver)

Answer (score 0):

You might have already known of IE driver.
Apart from that you also need to check Python version- Selenium2 version - IE Driver version - IE browser version compatibility.

Comment: Look, this question is 4.5 years ago. The project is long over. Anyway, thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @theheadofabroom 's answer, I should add that *Internet Explorer* does not play well with *Robot Framework*. Your test might not work for any number of reasons on *IE* while it may work just fine on *FireFox* and *Chrome*, but the most common is timing. *IE* is just slow enough that when *Robot Framework* goes to click on the next element, it searches the page for it, but it hasn't loaded in yet. As long as you have the *Selenium webdriver* for *IE* installed correctly and have written your *Robot Framework* code correctly, I'd recommend adding some `Sleep` keywords between actions to slow your code down and increase the probability that the element you want to click will load before *Robot Framework* searches the page for it. This is especially true if you're writing for *Chrome* and want to send it to either *Firefox* or *IE*.

Answer (score 0):

Robot class supports keyboard inputs regardless of the browser. It is a class from the java.awt package and not specific to any browser. It is used in automation for performing operations on the web browser(stand alone application) in which a web-page is being automated

Note that it cannot perform operations directly on the web browser as it's a stand alone application, but can make use of keyboard shortcuts to indirectly perform the operation.

For example, if you want to open a new tab in a browser, you can use the Robot class to press `Ctrl+t` instead of trying to click on the new tab.
Code to use it to open a new tab in your program

```
Webdriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); //FirefoxDriver(), IntrrnetExplorerDriver();
driver.get("......");
//code goes here
//to open a new tab
Robot rob = new Robot();
rob.keyPress(Keys.VK_CTRL);
rob.keyPress(Keys.VK_t);
rob.keyRelease(Keys.VK_CTRL);
rob.keyRelease(Keys.VK_t);
//itetator to switch between the tabs
```